# Python / Update of dictionaries in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of dictionaries like this:

```
abc = [{'aabb': 12}, {'ccdd': 23}, {'eeff': 34}]
```

and dictionary:

```
xyz = {'aabb': 1, 'ccdd': 2, 'eexx': 3}
```

and I have to check if keys from 'xyz' are in 'abc' and then update 'abc' dictionary.
Expected output:

```
abc = [{'aabb': 1}, {'ccdd': 2}, {'eeff': None}]
```

Comment: And ? What is your question ? What did you try ?

Comment: @Evan it is not my idea, i just have to work on data in this form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a *list comprehension* to build new dicts (with another dict comprehension) using values from `xyz`:

```
lst = [{k: xyz.get(k) for k in d} for d in abc]
print(lst)
# [{'aabb': 1}, {'ccdd': 2}, {'eeff': None}]
```

`dict.get` returns `None` for missing keys.